# When the kernel/kalloc.c: kmem global variables initialized

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, xv6, page-tables

I read the [xv6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) code and confused with the code in **kernel/kalloc.c:kmem** global variables. I didn't find any code do some initialization for **kmem**.
The kmem is a structure variable. I want to know when `kmem` initialized.

```
struct {
  struct spinlock lock;
  struct run *freelist;
} kmem;
```

code of kalloc.c github address [kalloc.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/kalloc.c)

Comment: Space is allocated for `kmem` by the code snippet you have shared. That's a C-style way of allocating "static" memory. The values (per C specification) are initialized to zero. The function `kinit` is called by [main](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/9ead904afef8d060c2cc5cee6bd8e8d223de8c40/kernel/main.c#L19) during startup. `kinit` sets the contents of `kmem.lock` and `kmem.run` to more useful values.

Comment: Is that means ``kmem`` point to a space of code segment, and was allocated at by compiler and the space value was assigned to useful values at ``kinit`` ?

Comment: Yes, the space for `kmem` was allocated at compile time. The space has a size of `sizeof( struct spinlock ) + sizeof( struct run* )`. By convention the compiler fills this space with zeros. You can see the space by looking at the generated `kalloc.o` file using a hex viewer. It is in the `.data` segment of the ELF (object) file. You can see the "code" (assembly instructions) in the `.text` section of the ELF file.

Comment: At run-time, `kinit` overwrites the zeros.

Comment: Technically `kmem` would be in the `.bss` section since it is uninitialized (instead of `.data`), but yes, the space is allocated at compile time and is "part of" the generated ELF file.